# java Socket programming Server Client

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to program a Server Client program where the CLIENT will be prompt if the SERVER closes or loses connection. What happens is once I connect the server and the client then disconnects the server it doesn't go to the `ConnectException` part
example: I opened the Server and Client connects, in the Client it will show that "You are connected to the Server", then if the Server disconnects there should be a "Server is disconnected". and when the Server reopens it will prompt the Client that he's connected to the Server

How can I continuously check if the Server is open or disconnected

here's my code:

**SERVER**

```
   public class Server
{
    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int port = 25000;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            //Server is running always. This is done using this while(true) loop
            while(true)
            {
                //Reading the message from the client
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client has connected!");
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String number = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message received from client is "+number);

                //Multiplying the number by 2 and forming the return message
                String returnMessage;
                try
                {
                    int numberInIntFormat = Integer.parseInt(number);
                    int returnValue = numberInIntFormat*2;
                    returnMessage = String.valueOf(returnValue) + "\n";
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    //Input was not a number. Sending proper message back to client.
                    returnMessage = "Please send a proper number\n";
                }

                //Sending the response back to the client.
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                bw.write(returnMessage);
                System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+returnMessage);
                bw.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
    public class Client
{
    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        try
        {
            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 25000;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("Connected to the Server");
        }
        catch (ConnectException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Server is still offline");
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Server got disconnected");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ConnectException Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. once you are connected, ConnectException will not be caught

Comment: then what Exception do I have to use to know If the client is disconnected from the server

Answer (score -1):

Well, the best way to tell if your connection is interrupted is to try to read/write from the socket. If the operation fails, then you have lost your connection sometime.

So, all you need to do is to try reading at some interval, and if the read fails try reconnecting.

The important events for you will be when a read fails - you lost connection, and when a new socket is connected - you regained connection.

That way you can keep track of up time and down time.

you can do like this

```
try
{
    Socket s = new Socket("address",port);
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    while (true)
    {
        os.writeBytes("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n");
        is.available();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
   }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("connection probably lost");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or you can simply et connection time out like this  `socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);` to check connectivity
or you can use

```
socket.getInputStream().read()
```

makes the thread wait for input as long as the server is connected and therefore makes your program not do anything - except if you get some input and 
returns -1 if the client disconnected
or what you can do is structure your code in this way

```
while(isConnected())
  {
      // do stuffs here
  }
```

Comment: ok, that solves one of the problem but how am I going to do it if...

I opened the client first before the server?

Comment: in any case it will catch exception if connection fails  and you can display general message like "Connection lost" or "error in connection"

Comment: so should i replace the thread.sleep to socket.setsotimeout(1000);? if yes it's the same when I open the client before the server it doesn't connect anymore

Comment: if you open a client before a server it will wait for timeout duration  for the server to connect

Comment: nope it just prints "server is offline" I've been running the program for almost 4 mnts but still no update...

Comment: what is value of time out you gave

Comment: socket.setsotimeout(1000);

Comment: its value in milisecond so it will just wait for 1 sec, try 10000 for 10 sec

Comment: still the same it doesn't detect the server when I opened client first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58859/discussion-between-askmaniac-and-jaimin).

Comment: @jaimin (1) It will fail immediately. It won't wait for a timeout. The timeout only happens when there is no response from the server at all. In this case the server will issue an RST which will result in an immediate 'connection refused'. (2) isConnected() doesn't magically become false when the peer disconnects.

Comment: @jaimin Why don't you fix your answer? I am commenting on the incorrect parts of your answer. That's what the comment system is for. That's how SO works. The suggestion that I should provide an answer instead, or as well, is fallacious.

Comment: where did `isConnected()` come from? (: